# Php Ratchet websocket request stuck without returning any response in postman

Tags: php, curl, websocket, postman, ratchet

I created basic websocket php to check and when i call the test file. The request take forever to complete. I followed the guide from [official docs](http://socketo.me/docs)

I call the test file from postman and postman stuck at sending response.... prompt.
When i call netstat -anp | grep LISTEN to check open ports mentioned in the above code, present in the list of open ports when request still waiting for the reply from onOpen.
There must be some issue with my code and i missed something from the official docs. Please help me and let me know if i miss anything.

I am calling this php to start a websockets.

```
<?php 
// API for privacy setting of user for blocking/Message Limit
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//file_put_contents('zee.log',print_r($_POST,true));

// Function to send the SDP and user IDs to the server
function sendSDP($sdp, $userIdA, $userIdB)
{
    // Create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the cURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "callSocketChat_2008.php");  `callSocketChat_2008.php` file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
        'sdp' => $sdp,
        'userIdA' => $userIdA,
        'userIdB' => $userIdB
    )));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Execute the cURL request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for errors
    if ($response === false) {
        echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        // Request successful, display the response
        echo $response;
    }

    // Close the cURL resource
    curl_close($ch);
}

// Test the sendSDP function
$sdp = "SDP valuexx YY"; // Replace with your actual SDP value
$userIdA = "4"; // Replace with your actual User ID A value
$userIdB = "8"; // Replace with your actual User ID B value

sendSDP($sdp, $userIdA, $userIdB);


?>
```

This is the Ratchet file where i am creating the socket.

```
<?php
// Enable error reporting and display errors for debugging purposes
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once("/home/bitnami/vendor/autoload.php");
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class WebSocketHandler implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage();
        print_r("Print Value ");
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Handle new WebSocket connection
        // You can add the connection to $this->clients for future reference
        //$request = $conn->httpRequest;
        //$userId = $_POST['userId']; // Assuming the user ID is received in the POST request

        // Save the user ID in the resourceId property of the connection
        $conn->resourceId = $userIdA;

        // Add the connection to the clients list
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        // Handle incoming WebSocket message
        // You can process the message and send a response back to the client
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Handle WebSocket connection close
        // You can remove the connection from $this->clients if necessary
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        // Handle WebSocket error
        // You can log or handle the error as needed
    }
}



// Get the SDP and user IDs from the request
$sdp = $_POST['sdp'];
$userIdA = $_POST['userIdA'];
$userIdB = $_POST['userIdB'];

// Fetch user details from the elaxer database using the user IDs
$userDetailsA = fetchUserDetails($userIdA);
$userDetailsB = fetchUserDetails($userIdB);

// Send push notification to wake up User B's device
//sendPushNotification($userDetailsB['fcmToken']);

// Wait for User B's device to establish a WebSocket connection
$waitForConnectionTimeout = 30; // Timeout in seconds
$startTime = time();
while (time() - $startTime < $waitForConnectionTimeout) {
    // Check if User B's device has connected to the WebSocket
    if (userDeviceConnected($userIdB)) {
        // User B's device connected, retrieve SDP from the elaxer database
        $sdpB = fetchSDP($userIdB);

        // Save User A's SDP in the elaxer database
        saveSDP($userIdA, $sdp);

        // Return User B's SDP to User A
        echo $sdpB;
        exit;
    }

    // Wait for a short duration before checking again
    sleep(1);
}


// Instantiate WebSocketHandler

//$server = \Ratchet\Server\IoServer::factory(
  //  new \Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
    //    new \Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer($webSocketHandler)
    //),
    //8080 // Change the port number if needed
//);

// Set up the WebSocket server using Ratchet
$server = Ratchet\Server\IoServer::factory(new WebSocketHandler(),20081); // Change the port number if needed
$server->run();




// Timeout reached, handle the case when User B's device didn't connect
handleTimeout();

// Fetch user details from the elaxer database using the user ID
function fetchUserDetails($userId)
{
    // Implement the logic to fetch user details from the elaxer database
    // Return an array containing the user details
}

// Send push notification to wake up User B's device
function sendPushNotification($fcmToken)
{
    // Implement the logic to send a push notification using FCM to the specified FCM token
}

// Check if User B's device has connected to the WebSocket
function userDeviceConnected($userId)
{
    // Implement the logic to check if User B's device has connected to the WebSocket
    // Return true if the device is connected, false otherwise
}

// Fetch SDP from the elaxer database using the user ID
function fetchSDP($userId)
{
    // Implement the logic to fetch SDP from the elaxer database using the user ID
    // Return the retrieved SDP
}

// Save SDP in the elaxer database using the user ID
function saveSDP($userId, $sdp)
{
    // Implement the logic to save the SDP in the elaxer database using the user ID
}

// Handle the case when User B's device didn't connect within the timeout
function handleTimeout()
{
    // Implement the logic to handle the timeout case
    // For example, you can return an error response or perform a fallback action
}


?>
```

**Edit:-** I tried postman websocket feature and then tried to call the php file but still i am not able to established connections. The error appears in console:-

```
Could not connect to ws://www.example.com/callSocketChat_2008.php
01:58:47
Error: Unexpected server response: 200
Handshake Details
Request URL: ws://www.example.com/callSocketChat_2008.php
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ansqUU0N7J4Q6S8PyR6XEg==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: www.example.com/callSocketChat_2008
Response Headers
Date: Tue, 30 May 2023 20:28:15 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**Edit 2** When i tried above code in terminal, with these steps:-

1. php callSocketChat_2008.php
2. telnet localhost 8080 with two more terminal.
3. Typing any message will reflects in other terminal too.

Then by following the official guide, next i move to the firefox browser to run below code:-

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://example.com:8080');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

The error i received,even when i tried with wss but its not working in browser.

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
> resource at ws://example.in:8080/ (“connect-src”). debugger eval
> code:1:11

Comment: A websocket connection isn't a HTTP request (although it builds on top of HTTP in a sense), so a simple cURL request isn't going to do the job. Use an actual websocket client - there are some for PHP you can find, or you can use JS, or you can [test it directly from postman](https://blog.postman.com/postman-supports-websocket-apis/).

Comment: @ADyson so the code you can see above with the curl ( i created just to test socket) expecting to call onOpen with echo command there.. I am doing wrong??

Comment: Why exactly do you expect that it will call the onOpen? Again, cURL just makes a standard HTTP request. To make a websocket connection, extra different steps are needed. Make sure you understand that Websockets and HTTP are different, as I mentioned. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket as an introduction, and you can find other explanations online too.

Comment: https://sookocheff.com/post/networking/how-do-websockets-work/

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the link and the suggestions. Now i tried with `ws` and `wss` but still getting error in console can you please look at it, why i am getting this error.

Comment: Are you still using cURL when you do that? cURL does not support websockets. Like I said in my first comment, please use some existing websocket client software. There is really no need to try to re-invent the wheel

Comment: @ADyson No. if you noticed in my error code i am calling the socket php file directly. I am not using curl for that

Comment: That's not how it works. You don't make the ws connection to a specific file, you make it to a URL and port number. The PHP script (if you've started the socket service properly) makes a script which listens on that port. Again, it's not HTTP...there are no filenames involved. Look again at the tutorial in the Ratchet documentation, in particular http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world#running_it

Comment: @ADyson The code above works well. I called the php file from terminal `php callSocketChat_2008.php ` then i use telnet to test it (exchanged messages ) and its worked but when i am trying same in browser it shows `content security policy` and it might because of browser security.

Comment: when you try _what_ in the browser, _exactly_? What _exactly_ is the message? I'm sure there is more detail than that. Details are important in programming. we cannot fix vaguely-described errors in unseen code. [edit] the question if you have more information to provide. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Yes you are right. So i made an edit with the steps and the error i am getting. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ` tag in your page, or a similar HTTP header being send from the server when the page is loaded? Have you done any [research into the common causes of this error](https://www.google.com/search?q=Content+Security+Policy%3A+The+page%E2%80%99s+settings+blocked+the+loading+of+a+resource)?

Comment: @ADyson The file you above is the actual file I'm calling from terminal. So as you saying is there any header, no it's not. I also googled that Firefox removed the developer tools from config where we can run JS like that.

Comment: None of that answers my question. It's not clear if you've actually checked what I asked, or not. You say there's no header, but have you actually used the network tab to check it? Have you verified there is no tag in the HTML? `the actual file I'm calling from terminal`...this has nothing to do with the terminal, we're talking about the page you're loading into your browser, which contains the JavaScript you posted.

Comment: @ADyson I am not loading any page in browser it's just a blank page with console open for typing the command

Comment: That's probably the issue then. Make a proper page to test with

Comment: i am following the official documentations-http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world . In new tab i just need to press F12 in firefox to open console to execute the JS command as per the official documentations and thats how i got the issue, you can try this at your end too.

Comment: Well ok, but maybe the documentation got out of date compared to browser security policies, or something. It's certainly worth trying it inside a web page, where you can control the security policy. Because this particular problem is in the browser, not in Ratchet.